# Multi-tenant identityserver openid authentication

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have a multi-tenant application which allows each tenant to have their own subdomain/custom domain and authentication. In this application I use OpenIdConnectAuthentication, is it possible to make the Authority dynamic (e.g. when a tenant has the subdomain tenant1.mysite.com or custom domain tenant1.com - the authority url would be login.tenant1.mysite.com or login.tenant1.com).

```
        var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {                
            AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
            SignInScheme = "Cookies",

            Authority = *dynamic*,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = *dynamic*,
            ClientId = "clientID",
            ClientSecret = "clientSecret",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
            SaveTokens = true
        };
```

I had a thought of possible creating a middleware to override the constructor for UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication but it didn't work and now I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I'm working on the same thing myself. How do you generate the token? Wouldn't that be the "authority"?

Comment: I also have this problem, I cant make the authentication middleware in ASP.NET 2.0+ use different IOptions object per request sine the ConfigureServices method in the Startup.cs file only runs once every application startup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working with this issue and so far IdentityModel library seems promising.

"You can programmatically create URLs for the authorize endpoint using the IdentityModel library"
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/authorize.html

IdentityModel library.
https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2

Comment: Did you able resolve this issue? If yes, can you please post an answer.